# How many subintervals have a interval of natural numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Consider the interval: $[1,n]$

How many subintervals does this interval have?

For example, $n = 3$ has 6 subintervals: $[1], [2], [3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3]$

Comment: Any non-empty subset gives a chain, so there should be $2^n-1$ of them, yes? Unless you are also excluding all of $A$, in which case you should have $2^n-2$.

Comment: well that can't be true since it does not hold with $n=4$, I think...

wouldn't $\{1,3,4\}$ and $\{1,2,4\}$ give the same interval?

Comment: @VanillaThunder Except that it does? Maybe you are referring to my comment before the edit.

Comment: @VanillaThunder The OP seems to have found 6 intervals when $n=3$.  user546996's computation indicates that there should be $2^3 - 2 = 6$.  What is the problem?

Comment: not sure which correspondence you see between subsets and intervals

Comment: @VanillaThunder If you pick a subset of natural numbers they form a chain since the naturals are totally ordered?

Comment: @user546996 I fat-fingered the [enter] key while typing---I was not contradicting you at all.  NB:  I *really* don't like the keyboard on the most recent generation of Apple laptops. :\

Comment: @user546996 check out my comment above!! I edited it a while ago...

Comment: That being said, I am not sure that I understand what is meant by a "chain".  I feel like chains and intervals aren't really the same thing in most settings...

Comment: @VanillaThunder Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, as the answer that has been posted below has nothing to do with chains. Your edit to consider the case $n=4$ with the two examples still falls inside the scope of my original comment, since those are both subsets of $[4]$ and can be made into chains with the usual ordering.

Comment: @XanderHenderson My understanding is that a chain is a subset of a poset that is totally ordered, along the lines of Zorn's Lemma chains.

Comment: @user546996 Mine, too.  Which is different from an interval.  Hence my confusion.  Some input from the OP would be helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A range is specified by its largest and smallest elements, $x$ and $y$. If $x=n$, then there are $n$ choices for $y$, anything between $1$ and $n$ inclusive. If $x=(n-1)$, there are $n-1$ choices for $y$, and so on.

Continuing in this pattern, the number of ranges is $$n+(n-1)+(n-2)+\dots+2+1=n(n+1)/2.$$

Comment: This is relevant to a comment on the problem, but what does this have to do with chains? Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: as op has marked this as correct I suppose, that he does not want to know about chains, but about intervals and Mike and me git him right out of pure luck